# Is there any admin panel for a firebase firestore console?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

is there any admin panel for firebase apart from its console? Or what's the easiest way to build a admin dashboard for firebase?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, somewhat curiously, Firestore is not fully incorporated into `gcloud`, the most likely CLI where this functionality could exist.

The Firebase CLI includes very limited [database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands) functionality.

[Fuego](https://github.com/sgarciac/fuego) is a 3rd-party tool that includes a chunk of useful functionality.